# Sharing a behavior across all View types in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

I want to implement RTL option to all views and Layouts, what I'm going to do is to invert `LayoutOptions`, so if it's `Start` I make it `End` and vice versa,

I want to create a behavior that is shared across all views, it would be pain to attach it to all views, so Is there a way to make it generic that any `View` type can have this behavior without changing XAML?

Comment: Why not create your own `MyRTLControl` which inherits from the regular control and attaches the behavior. Then just use the `MyRTLControl` everywhere.

Comment: Then I will create `MyRTL***` for all controls,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, sorry

Comment: I will Create a Control for, `Entry`, `Label`, `Grid`, `StackLayout`..etc (any `View` type), to achieve the same thing. that's the problem I want to avoid

Comment: would it be acceptable to go from top element down through the entire visualtree and invert everything you need on every control? what do you mean by RTL? text reversal? or just alignments?

Comment: @Milan I mean by RTL reversing any  property related to direction of the language so `Start` becomes `End` for `LayoutOptions`, and so for the `TextAlignment`

Comment: what about the visual tree question? could you afford to do that? you dont change RTL too often :/

Comment: @Milan No, this is a basic functionality , that will be in all pages

Comment: you consider it too much if you have to write: HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=GlobalAlignmentValue}" for every element in your xaml? did i understand this right?